# How to integrate shibboleth idp to an existing Spring application?

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I have an exisiting Spring web application with user authentication logic implemented.

Is there a way to integrate the Shibboleth IDP to my application so I can resue the exisitng authentication logic and provide IDP easy access to user attributes.

By integration I mean, the exisitng application and idp should be pacakged and deployed to Jetty in a single .war file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to integrate the Shibboleth IDP to my application so I can resue the exisitng authentication logic and provide IDP easy access to user attributes.

No.

> By integration I mean, the exisitng application and idp should be pacakged and deployed to Jetty in a single .war file.

No, that is not possible. The exisitng application and idp should be separately pacakged and deployed to Jetty in two .war files.